# how to create a button that can be drag and drop on other button in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to create some button that can drag and drop to other button 
( both button are same component )
I have actually 6 button on my web application.
Each button get his text from his constructor and can be drag and drop on any of the other button.

I can't find any example of how to do it.
I don't know how to do it.

Comment: This might be of use:
https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd

Comment: @DacreDenny: saw it - but in this the component is only the 'DragSource' so from what i understand this make this component possible to be drag but on drop on the same controller kind ( for example i want to create button 1,2,3 and i want to drad button 1 on 3 .. the DragSource make the button to be drag but on drop on 3 )

Comment: Why not introduce a button drop component that wraps buttons - this new component would be annotated as a DropTarget (http://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/docs-drop-target.html). So in other words, decouple the DragSource and DropTarget behaviors into separate components to achieve what you want

Comment: @DacreDenny: ok .. this can be fit but i looking for code example that work